# dataframe to json results in single row output

Tags: python, json, dataframe

Dataframe with shape 1000x55 I exported to Json with:

```
full_dataset_df.to_json('fulldataset.json')
```

When loading the json file in another notebook with read_json I get all data in one row with all data in every single cell.

Example column of indexes shows: {'0':0,'1':1,'2':2...} 
The dimension is then 1x55 with all data like this in every cell.

How can the dataframe properly being exported to json to properly read it in?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `orient` property of `to_json` and `read_json`. As long as you are consistent writing and reading it should work fine!

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

Comment: thanks for replying @alvaroP. I tried all orient types but didnt work. As I see in pandas documentation output should be with column numbers?

df.to_json(orient='records')
'[{"col 1":"a","col 2":"b"},{"col 1":"c","col 2":"d"}]'

Comment: can you provide some more info and perhaps a snippet of your data frame?

Comment: Ofcourse. The data is obtained in a json, readin, that works and then I merge two json files in one with concat (both files have same columns, just concatenating the rows). Then I want to write the dataframe to json. After writing the output the jsonfile contains of all data in 1 row nested and does not have the dimensions of the dataframe. The dataframe contains strings and numbers with all varieties.